# Shopping cart almost working

Tags: java

Am unable to still get this program working like it should. Most of it works, see code below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class demo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    String str[] = { "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges" };
    double price[] = { 2.09, 3.99, 2.19};
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter type of product: ");
    String string = sc.next();
    if ("fruit".equals(string)) {
        while (i < str.length) {
            while (j < price.length) {
                System.out.print(str[i++] + ": " + "£" + (price[j++]) + "p per bag \n");

            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("Enter which type of " + string + ": ");

    String string1 = sc.next();

    boolean strs = "bananas".equals(string1);
    boolean strs1 = "apples".equals(string1);
    boolean strs2 = "oranges".equals(string1);


    if (strs){
        System.out.print("Enter qty of " + str[0] + " (by bag): ");
    }

    if (strs1) {
        System.out.print("Enter qty of " + str[1] + " (by bag): ");

    }
    if (strs2) {
        System.out.print("Enter qty of " + str[2] + " (by bag): ");
    }

    int qty = sc.nextInt();
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int h = 1;
    int[] g = {0,1,2};

    if ((a[h] == (qty))  || (strs) || (strs1) || (strs2)) {
        System.out.print("\n"+ qty + " bag(s) of " + string1 + " have been added to your basket, " 
        + "total costing £"+ (qty) * (price[g[0]]) + "p");



    }

    }

}
```

How can I get this code to work...any ideas?(ie the type of product(fruit), the type of fruit(bananas or apples or oranges), and the qty of them (between 1-10), but when it comes to working out Total cost, it comes out wrong...

Comment: Just a hint: `h` is always 1 and `g[0]` is also the same for each execution.

Comment: I need to get the cost of  fruit types and multiply that by qty ordered (obvious).but how do I do without user input, for the cost of fruit types. Hmm...

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Does BufferedReader allow values to be read as well as get user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One logic is this.

```
double itemCost = 0;
if (strs){
    System.out.print("Enter qty of " + str[0] + " (by bag): ");
    itemCost = price[0]; 
}

if (strs1) {
    System.out.print("Enter qty of " + str[1] + " (by bag): ");
    itemCost = price[1]; 
}
if (strs2) {
    System.out.print("Enter qty of " + str[2] + " (by bag): ");
    itemCost = price[2]; 
}

int qty = sc.nextInt();
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int h = 1;
int[] g = {0,1,2};

if ((a[h] == (qty))  || (strs) || (strs1) || (strs2)) {
    System.out.print("\n"+ qty + " bag(s) of " + string1 + " have been added to your basket, " 
    + "total costing £"+ (qty) * (itemCost) + "p");
```